# Salesforce Production Org - Login action link missing in Users in Manage Users->Users. How to login as other user?

Tags: sandbox, user, production

I am trying to login as other users in production org using Login action link in Manager Users --> Users page. But i did not find the link except the Edit action link but in sandbox. How to login as other users and verify the functionality and features and simulate to see how it behaves? Is there any other alternate way to do that? Why the login link missing in Production org? Any suggestions please. Please note i logged in system administrator.

**Below Screen shot shows Login link in sandbox org.**

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Have you enabled the feature for your production org? In a production org, the user also needs to authorize you to log-in under their User ID. That's why its production and not a sandbox.

Comment: Thanks @crmprogdev. Could you please tell what feature i need to enable in production org?

Comment: SF has to enable it for you. Oh, I see someone else posted the answer for you. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Login as User feature is turned on by default in Sandboxes but you need to contact SalesForce to get it turned on in other orgs.

> **To enable this login access policy:**
>
> Step 1. Contact salesforce.com support to have this feature enabled in your organization first.
>
> **You can’t complete the remaining steps until salesforce.com support
>   enables the feature.  Please ask for this permission to be enabled on
>   the backend:**
>
> - "Enables Org Admins to log in as any user without having access granted by the users"
> - "Organization Administrators Can Log in as Any User - Summer 12"**
>
> Step 2. After step 1 above is complete, Click Your Name > Setup > Security Controls > Login Access Policies.
>
> Step 3. On the Login Access Policies page, enable Administrators Can Log in as Any User.
>
> Step 4. Click Save.

[Reference](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000089838&language=en_US)

Comment: Thanks BatCotter. I would raise a support ticket with salesforce for this.

Answer (score 0):

You may be unable to grant access to certain support organizations due to restrictions set up by your administrator or based on the type of licensing used by a packaged application.